# How to add class to view block programmatically

Tags: 7, blocks, views, theming

I need to add class to view block programmatically, but could not find working way to do it.
 My view format is Unformatted list. 
I have this in my template.php:

```
function theme_preprocess_block(&$variables){

  // Add arbitrary class to specific block
  if ($variables['block']->module == 'front_tiles') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'my-special-class';
  }
}
```

Any help?

**SOLVED**
Changing:

```
if ($variables['block']->module == 'front_tiles') {
```

To:

```
if ($variables['block']->module == 'views') {
```

Now it will affect to views blocks.

Comment: The code seems correct.
Have you tried to set a breakpoint and see if it's enter in the if block ?

Comment: No I have not, but when I change "if ($variables['block']->module == 'front_tiles')" to  "if ($variables['block']->module == 'block')" Then it adds class to all NORMAL blocks, not to views blocks. How to make this affect to views blocks?